# git: Find the oldest commit of `mine` which does not exist in `theirs`

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I'd like to be able to find the longest path in my git-graph which does not exist upstream. One end of that path is obviously HEAD, so that's easy. The other end is my oldest commit which does not exist upstream. I don't know how to find this.

Diagram

```
[otherguy]   H--I--J   
            /       \
[master]   A--B--C--M1--D--E--M2--F--G
              \      \             \
[mine]         H---I--M3---J---K---M4--M--HEAD
```

I want a command which will point me to H (or B), given `HEAD` and `master`. Note that a simple `git merge-base master HEAD` gives me F.

Comment: Something like `git-log --oneline master..HEAD` and grab the last line?  See [`git-rev-parse`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) for more info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work reasonably:

```
git rev-list --topo-order --reverse mine ^master | head -1
```

Tested with a replica of your setup, it prints the commit you marked as "H". I am not 100% convinced that it finds the "farthest" path in all possible cases, or that such a concept is even well-defined, so you might want to test it on cases that matter to you before relying on it.

(Note that the `-1` option one would usually specify to limit `git rev-list` output does not combine well with `--reverse`, so `head -1` is needed.)

---

UPDATE:

Some explanation:

- `git rev-list mine ^master` requests the commits reachable from `mine`, but not from `master`. In your case we are requesting all commits starting with `HEAD`, excluding those reachable from `G`, which gives a list of commits `(M, M4, K, J, M3, I, H)`, of which we choose the last one.
- `--topo-order` is needed to ensure topological ordering of commits (that a commit always appears before its parent), rather than chronological ordering, which is the default. We also specify `--reverse` because we need the last one.
- `commit1 ^commit2` can also be spelled `commit2..commit1`, which is the preferred syntax when `commit1` is a descendant of `commit2`. In this case `mine` and `master` have diverged, so it's clearer to spell out what we want. Multiple exclusions, such as `git log branch1 ^branch2 ^branch3`, are also allowed. This applies to all git commands that take ranges, and is documented in the [`git rev-parse` manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html).

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: `git log branch1 ^branch2` means "show me commits reachable from `branch1`, excluding those that are also visible from `branch2`", i.e. only those specific to `branch1`. In this case we are requesting all commits starting with `HEAD`, excluding those reachable from `G`. This gives us a list of commits `(M, M4, K, J, M3, I, H)`, of which we choose the last one.

Comment: `branch1 ^branch2` can also be spelled `branch2..branch1`, the preferred syntax when `branch1` is a linear descendant of `branch2`. In this case it is clearer to spell out explicitly what to include and what to exclude. Multiple exclusions are also possible, such as `git log branch1 ^branch2 ^branch3`. This applies to all git commands that take ranges, and is documented in the [`git rev-parse` manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) under "specifying ranges".

Comment: I've now updated the answer with the cleaned-up contents of my last two comments.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer. Don't you think it's time to update your username?

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly equivalent to the question »Which commits are reachable from (my) HEAD, but not from master?« To answer that question, use the commit range `master..HEAD`. You want the oldest commit from this list, so pipe the output through tail: `git rev-list master..HEAD|tail -n1`.

If your commit timestamps are not ordered chronologically, you might have to specify the `--topo-order` option to rev-list.

Comment: Note that `git rev-list --reverse -n1` does not do what one would expect. Also, `git rev-list` sorts chronologically by default, and the OP doesn't want the oldest commit, but the farthest one in the tree, so he also needs `--topo-order`.

Comment: @user4815162342: very correct. Thanks for the headsup. Most of the time, one can assume chronological ordering of commits too, but I will update my answer.